# Misunderstanding of the definition of support of a function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

The function in question is

$$f(x)=(x^3 - x) \chi_{[-1,1]}(x)$$

[image]

In a credible source, I find that the support is

$$\text{supp} f=[-1,1],$$

and compact.

My question is regarding the value at $x=0.$

If the definition of support is correctly understood as the set $$\{x \in \mathbb R ; f(x) \neq 0\},$$

and compact when bounded (i.e. with support bounded between two values in a closed interval $[a,b],$ then the support is interrupted (not compact) at zero.

Why wouldn't the support be $[-1,0) \cup (0,1]$?

Comment: It seems to me that the support is defined as the closure of the set you describe, although what is says [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)#Closed_support) is somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: @saulspatz Thank you. That makes sense. In fact, isn't that what I unwittingly wrote at the very end of the question? The closure... :-)

Comment: $[-1, 0) \cup (0, 1]$ is not a closed set.

Comment: The definition of the support is as follows: a point is NOT in the support if the function vanishes on a neighborhood of the point (including the point itself).

Comment: @Deane so in this case $x=0$ is in the support because in their infinitesimal neighbouring values the function is not zero? Not clear about "vanishing"...

Comment: That’s correct.